# Contao 4 Front-end login does not work like contao 3.5

Tags: contao

Contao 4 suggests to use form to log in to the front-end: https://docs.contao.org/manual/en/layout/module-management/user-modules/
But I am looking for a solution in my own created login module.
I have a user name (email) and password.
I would like to create my own function to log in and log out in the frontend.
Need a solution. please help.

Answer (score 0):

Contao's firewall will react to any POST request with the following parameters:

```
FORM_SUBMIT=tl_login
username=…
password=…
```

See the [ContaoLoginAuthenticationListener](https://github.com/contao/contao/blob/4.9/core-bundle/src/Security/Authentication/ContaoLoginAuthenticationListener.php) (*note:* it is different in Contao 4.4).

So as long as your own login module causes these POST request parameters to be sent (+ `REQUEST_TOKEN` if necessary), then the user should be automatically logged in.

Comment: Yes, know this. for form submit this is fine. but i need auto-login without submitting the form. For example, I have a URL with some hash code that would auto-login to contao 4.  
So, no form submit but another solution.

Comment: Then you might need to implement a Guard Authenticator: https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/security/guard_authentication.html